# Android Fileprovider: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: pdf, authority, android-fileprovider

I have a question about the android FileProvider.
I want to save a pdf document and open it with a default program.
I don´t want to save it in external Storage.

After I´ve successfully saved the pdf to the FilesDirectory/export/temp.pdf,
I´ve tried to generate an URI by using FileProvider.getUriForFile().

```
File path = new File(getFilesDir(), "export");
File pdf = new File(path + File.separator + "temp.pdf");
pdf.getParentFile().mkdirs();

if (!pdf.exists())
    pdf.createNewFile();

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "?", pdf);
```

Question: What do I have to pass as the second parameter "Authority" - the location of my Files, the class which can grant the URI-Permissions or something other? Whatever I´ve tried leaded to an IllegalArgumentException or a NullPointerException.
My FileProvider (XML):

```
<provider         
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"           
        android:authorities="com.example.myApp.myActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data                 
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"                           
             android:resource="@xml/file_path"/>                                       
</provider>
```

referenced File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="pdfTemplates" path="export/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Have you found an answer yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I´ve got it. There were two different Problems

1. The first Issue was answered by CodeDiving.
   I had to use the Authority from the provider-declaration for the getUriForFile call. Using an other class caused the NullPointerException.
2. I´ve tried to get a file from filesDirectory, but in my file_path I declared only a path to cache Directory. I changed it to 'files-path' and it worked. This error caused the IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Make sure that it is `files-path` and not `file-path`. Easily missed!

Comment: Where does this `files-path` go?  I mean where do you specify it.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky he replaced the `<cache-path` with `<files-path` inside the referenced xml file _file_path_.

Comment: FileProvider docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: If you are using `getCacheDir()` then can use `cache-path` instead of `files-path`. If you are dumping files straight into getCacheDir, then you don't need to specify `path=`

Answer (score 9):

According to your FileProvider file(XML), the second parameter is `com.example.myApp.myActivity`. That is

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                     "com.example.myApp.myActivity", pdf);
```