# Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am trying to open the pdf file which I downloaded & saved in external storage. But When I open my app its gets crashed and showing following error;

```
08-31 00:58:31.304 1807-1807/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: medimanage.corporate.mobile, PID: 1807
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:586)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:375)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Following is my async task where I download that pdf file & trying to open it.

```
package myPackageName.common.postData;    
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog Dialog;
        private Context mContext;
        private String folder_main; //= "TermCondition";
        private String fileName;//= "termCondition.pdf";
        String urlString;

        public DownloadFileFromURL(Context mContext, String folderName) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.folder_main = folderName;
            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.mContext);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            try {
                urlString = f_url[0];
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), this.folder_main);
                if (folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdirs();
                } 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "default.pdf");
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_DISMISS];
                while (true) {
                    int bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if (bufferLength <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                FileLog.e(mContext.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
                FileLog.e(mContext.getClass().getName(), e2);
            } catch (IOException e3) {
                FileLog.e(mContext.getClass().getName(), e3);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void showPdf() {
            try {

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "default.pdf");

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "medimanage.corporate.mobile.fileprovider", file);
                        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");
                    } else {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                    }
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "No activity found to open this attachment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                FileLog.e(mContext.getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
            Dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            this.Dialog.dismiss();
            showPdf();
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

    }
```

Following is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
...>
  <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="myPackageName.fileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDE_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
  </provider>
</application>
```

And provider_paths.xml having following code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="Android/data/" name="files_root" />
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

I am trying to run above code in API 19 & API 25, but in both devices its gets crash. I am not able to find out where I am going wrong.

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978198/android-file-provider-illegal-argument-exception) & also [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#ProviderDefinition) too but not able to find a solution to my issue.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111284/7666442 and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345275/android-fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-th and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263428/android-fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-t

Comment: @NileshRathod According to your referred links I replace following lines in provider_paths.xml file;
`<paths>
    <files-path path="/storage/emulated" name="files_root" />
    <files-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>`
but still its crashing.

Comment: did it work or not  @priyanka kamthe

Comment: no, its not works for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263428/android-fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-t

Comment: `android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDE_PATHS"` ??? R missing! If you catch that exception your app will not crash.

Comment: @greenapps I'm not able to understand, R missing means?

Comment: PROVIDE + R i would say you have a typo.

Comment: @greenapps thnx. Very silly mistake. Its working now.

Comment: I have used .provider in my authority name & its accepted, only the fact that if I am having more than 1 provider, then file provider should be declared first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest file, you have a slight typo in the metadata:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" <-- HERE!!!
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```

You need to use FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS instead of FILE_PROVIDE_PATHS.

Comment: Do you mean that `FILE_PROVIDE_PATHS` is the correct one? I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

Please do invalidate caches and restart function in android studio, most probably that will do.

After that rebuild and run your app. In my case it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like something is set wrong, The compiler doesn't find android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS , thus, it throws this error, check if everything is set correctly in your gradle file, if you change the package of the android.support this exception might arise.

After fixing, do a clean, rebuild, or clean and invalidate cache in Android studio.

Answer (score 3):

Provider in AndroidManifest.xml, if you using AndroidX library.

```
  <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.yourdomain.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is often caused by a typo, where you might use **android:value** instead of **android:resource** in the meta-data tag specifying the **file_paths.xml** file. For example you might have:

```
android:value="@xml/file_paths"
```

instead of

```
android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
```

Answer (score 2):

There was no problem when using before (same test machine), but suddenly this problem appeared, I do not know what the reason is.I looked up some references, changed the suffix, and the problem was solved

Previous code

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

The modified code

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I had the same issue.

If you have a line that looks something like this:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,"${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileProvider", tmpFile)
```

Just make sure that the `fileProvider` string matches *exactly* what is declared in your manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider" //<--MATCH THIS!!
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

And note that is *is case sensitive*.

That solved it for me, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. and no other solution worked for me. I closed the project from Android Studio and then manually deleted the .gradle and .idea files and it worked like a charm :) . And earlier i had an issue with the authorities - point it to the fileprovider you use with your applicationId . Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes everything with your code is just fine, but you switch branches and the old build intermediates are reused and this happens. For me, just removing the `build/intermediates` dir, and then building and running the app again worked. This is almost equivalent (but faster) to cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score -1):

Android: Convert value + resource=@xml/file_paths"

Comment: Try to provide some more details. Like what was the problem? How your approach works better or different than the accepted answer and so on.

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem,just delete all .gradle and and build folder and then rebuild app worked for me

Comment: You should probably be more precise when answering questions, with providing explainations about the source of the problem.